# Determine the ranking of groups in a self referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, data-structures, hierarchical-data

I'm struggling with recursive CTE again. I have a self-referencing table with score associated to each row. I need to resolve the sort order of the leaf nodes by score correspond to the sort order of parent nodes (also sorted by score). The grouping looks like this:

```
Groups                  Score
------------------------------------
Group 1                 0.95
    Group a             0.7
        Group i         0.9
        Group ii        0.7
    Group b             0.9
        Group iii       0.5
        Group iv        1.0
Group 2                 0.9
    Group c             0.5
    Group d             0.8
Group 3                 1.0
```

This is the expected result set:

```
GroupID     GroupName   Score   Rank
------------------------------------
11          Group 3     1.0     1
7           Group iv    1.0     2
6           Group iii   0.5     3
3           Group i     0.9     4
4           Group ii    0.7     5
10          Group d     0.8     6
9           Group c     0.5     7
```

Here's sample records. Thanks in advance.

```
declare @tblGroups table (
            GroupID int,
            GroupName nvarchar(50),
            ParentID int,
            Score float
)

insert into @tblGroups values (1, 'Group 1', null, 0.95)
insert into @tblGroups values (2, 'Group a', 1, 0.7)
insert into @tblGroups values (3, 'Group i', 2, 0.9)
insert into @tblGroups values (4, 'Group ii', 2, 0.7)
insert into @tblGroups values (5, 'Group b', 1, 0.9)
insert into @tblGroups values (6, 'Group iii', 5, 0.5)
insert into @tblGroups values (7, 'Group iv', 5, 1.0)

insert into @tblGroups values (8, 'Group 2', null, 0.9)
insert into @tblGroups values (9, 'Group c', 8, 0.5)
insert into @tblGroups values (10, 'Group d', 8, 0.8)

insert into @tblGroups values (11, 'Group 3', null, 1.0)

select 
    g.* 
from 
    @tblGroups g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on the comments below, it seems that the problem is rather easier than I thought:

```
declare @tblGroups table ( GroupId int, GroupName nvarchar(50), ParentId int, Score float ) 
insert into @tblGroups values (1, 'Group 1', null, 0.95)    
insert into @tblGroups values (2, 'Group a', 1, 0.7)    
insert into @tblGroups values (3, 'Group i', 2, 0.9)    
insert into @tblGroups values (4, 'Group ii', 2, 0.7)    
insert into @tblGroups values (5, 'Group b', 1, 0.9)    
insert into @tblGroups values (6, 'Group iii', 5, 0.5)    
insert into @tblGroups values (7, 'Group iv', 5, 1.0)    

insert into @tblGroups values (8, 'Group 2', null, 0.9)    
insert into @tblGroups values (9, 'Group c', 8, 0.5)    
insert into @tblGroups values (10, 'Group d', 8, 0.8)    

insert into @tblGroups values (11, 'Group 3', null, 1.0)    

select * from @tblGroups

; with Greg as (
  -- The roots have no parents.
  select GroupId, GroupName, ParentId, Score,
    Cast( Right( '00000' + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by Score desc ) as VarChar(6) ), 6 ) as VarChar(1024) ) as OverallRank
    from @tblGroups
    where ParentId is NULL
  union all
  -- Add the children one generation at a time.
  select T.GroupId, T.GroupName, T.ParentId, T.Score,
    Cast( G.OverallRank + Right( '00000' + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by T.Score desc ) as VarChar(6) ), 6 ) as VarChar(1024) )
    from Greg as G inner join
      @tblGroups as T on T.ParentId = G.GroupId
  )
  select *
    from Greg as G
    where not exists ( select 42 from @tblGroups where ParentId = G.GroupId ) -- Leaf nodes only.
    order by OverallRank
```

Comment: Yah, this does not keep track of the parent's score all the way up. It just HAPPENS to work out in this case, but change Group1 to a .4 and it still gives the same output, when everything under group1 should drop down to the bottom of the parent nodes: This can bee seen here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0b64/2   It basically only checks the max score of the immediate parent, not propogating to the top

Comment: @JustinPihony - Actually it does keep track of the scores.  I'm just a little unclear on what the OP really wants by way of sorting in an erratic kind of way.

Comment: The sorting is not erratic, it is based on the parent for each one. To try to explain it better, it is sorting the top parents, then it sorts the children, but based on the top parent (so, it is like saying if parent1 is the top sort, then ALL of its children take precedence over ANY of parent2's children)...does that explain it better?

Comment: @JustinPihony - Okay, that makes more sense.

Comment: @user92546 - That's a very interesting approach. What's `select 42` mean?

Comment: @Eric An EXISTS does not even use the SELECT portion of the subquery, so you can put just about anything you want. You supposedly can even do a 1/0

Comment: @Eric - 42 is "The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything".  As noted, `EXISTS` doesn't care what you select, so I tend to use 42 as a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this SHOULD work. The `RIGHT` is to make sure if there is a 12 that the order remains 6 digits or else it will overlap and mess up the next recursion level

```
WITH myCTE
AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Score desc) AS RowNumber, 
      RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Score desc) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),6) AS Overall
  FROM tblGroups
  WHERE ParentId IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT tblGroups.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myCTE.RowNumber , tblGroups.Score desc) AS RowNumber,
       Overall + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myCTE.RowNumber , tblGroups.Score desc) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),6) AS Overall
  FROM tblGroups
      JOIN myCTE
          ON myCTE.GroupID = tblGroups.ParentID
 )

SELECT *
FROM myCTE
          WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tblGroups AS ParentTbl
        WHERE myCTE.GroupID = ParentTbl.ParentID
      )
ORDER BY overall;
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1248d/1)

Comment: Thanks Justin. But how do I resolve the ranking? I tried it with 'rank() over(order by Score desc)' but 'Group iii' and 'Group c' have the same score and I end up with duplicate ranking.

Comment: I'm guessing it should be done in set. Using procedural language, the iteration would be like this: get all root nodes sorted by score desc >> get all child nodes in `Group 1` sorted by score desc >> get all child nodes in `Group b` sorted by score desc >> rank all children and save ..

Comment: @Eric I have updated my answer. The first sql is just what I think the CTE should do (but doesnt), and then how to accomplish it via a while loop. This is basically doing what the recursive CTE SHOULD be doing behind the scenes. (I plan on asking why the CTE works the way it does as I dont agree with it)

Comment: I still have a little problem. I've update the sample to cover all possible scenarios. I added `Group 3` and it doesn't have any child nodes.

Comment: @Eric It should still work: sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dfec/1 And, if this worked and you like it, upvotes are always appreciated :-p

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to update the scores on `Group 1` and `Group 2`. Can you try it again? I added `Group 3`. It has the highest score with no child nodes.

Comment: @eric This is messy code, so I will fix it up before putting it as the answer, but I had the way of the ordering wrong. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f67a2/12

Comment: @Eric Even better, I have made the CTE work:  This should fit what you need: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1248d/1

Comment: Very much appreciate you help and I mean it. I've spent hours on this issue. But I had to give the credit to user92546 since your approach on the last update is near identical to his.